# Could not find gn executable at: C:\...\buildtools\win\gn.exe

Tags: build, electron, gn, gclient

I'm running into the following error:

```
Could not find gn executable at: C:\...\JavaScriptApplications\electron\buildtools\win\gn.exe
```

after running the following `gclient` command as part of the instructions to [build electron from source](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/development/build-instructions-gn):

```
gn gen out/Release --args="import(\"//electron/build/args/release.gn\")"
```

**Note:** I've already found some possible solutions that I would like to share in order to help anyone else running into this error.

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I ended up resolving the issue by manually creating the folder structure `buildtools\win\` at the specified path and then moving the `gn.exe` file I downloaded from the [gn website](https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/) into it.

Later I realized the issue could be due to me running that `gclient` command in a Git Bash terminal in VSCode instead of the intended Command Prompt.

Indeed, running the `gclient` commands via Command Prompt as Administrator worked as expected.